# Apache PHP relative path not recognised

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, ushahidi

I'm stuck with installing Ushahidi Platform client. I got the API working thanks to mod rewrite. Now I'm setting up the platform client but I have no success doing it.

So here's my html docs set up:

html 

      index.html

      about.html

      platform-client <~ subdirectory

          server

          www

              .htaccess

              index.html

here's my .htaccess in my platform-client:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.html  [PT,L]
```

Here's platform-client/server/www/index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-strict-di>
<head ng-controller="PageMetadata">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="/fonts/Lato/css/fonts.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <!-- @todo minify CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" ng-href="{{rtlEnabled ? '/css/rtl-style.css' : '/css/style.css'}}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/vendor.css">
    <script src="/config.js"></script>

    <title ng-bind-template="{{pageTitle}} {{siteTitle}}"></title>
    <meta name="description" content="{{pageDescription}}">
    <meta name="keywords" content="{{pageKeywords}}">
    <meta name="robots" content="{{pageRobots}}">
    <base href="/">
</head>

<body ng-class="{ rtl : rtlEnabled }" class="has-dynamic-header" canvas>
    <div id="bootstrap-loading">
        <header class="header header-full overlay" role="banner">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="color-overlay">
                    <div class="parallax">
                        <h1 class="beta"><i class="fa fa-refresh fa-4 fa-spin"></i></h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
    </div>
```

etc....

When I run the site, I'm getting the error display and not the correct one. When I also inspect the element I see that /css/style.css is pointing to my root directory which is the domain.

```
 www.example.com/css/style.css
```

it should be:

```
www.example.com/platform-client/server/www/css/style.css
```

UPDATE: here's my httpd.conf:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias www.example.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/platform-client/server/www
ServerName example.com/platform-client/server/www
<Directory "/var/www/html/platform-client/server/www">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Any problems with my set up? I really need your help 'coz I've been fixing this for almost a week without success. I would gladly appreciate any kind of help. Thanks!

Comment: Assuming that the index.html you display is the one within the /platform-client/www/ folder, you could try dropping the leading slash in the link:
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

Comment: @Gralgrathor thanks for your reply. I tried that to no avail. Still getting the error

Comment: So what's the actual request URI coming in resulting in the error? What do you type into the browser to get the index.html you listed?

Comment: @Gralgrathor I type www.example.com/platform-client/server/www to view index.html

Comment: Right, so your docroot is right at the top of the folder structure you listed. Meaning that the <link href="..."> should point to a location relative to that docroot. Eg. <link rel="stylesheet" href="/platform-client/server/www/css/style.css">. Or so I would think. Unless there's a lot more rewrites in your .htaccess.

Comment: @Gralgrathor I've updated my post with httpd.conf. Can you please check? Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107378/discussion-between-betty-barnes-and-gralgrathor).

Comment: You have 2 VirtualHosts, but the second one is not used, the first one acts as a default if no one is found by checking `ServerName`. Check [ServerName](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/core.html#servername) directive, it must be in the form of `ServerName [scheme://]domain-name|ip-address[:port]` and not a path.

Comment: @Zimmi how can I change it? I'm new to this. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

So, to solve this, add the following A-record to your DNS entry:

```
*    A    <your host's ip-address>
```

Every possible subdomain of your domain will now point to the same host. Your hosting provider probably allows you to add DNS entries through some configuration panel, like cpanel. If they do, be careful about what you change. Committing the wrong changes can leave your host off the air for hours. If they don't allow a "*" as your subdomain, then just enter the specific subdomain you require.

Then, include the following two VirtualHosts in your httpd.conf - ideally as includes to the /etc/apache2/sites-enabled folder, but you can worry about beautifying your configuration later:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@<yourdomain>.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ServerName www.<yourdomain>.com
    ServerAlias <yourdomain>.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@<yourdomain>.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/platform-client/server/www
    ServerName <subdomain>.<yourdomain>.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Ideally, you should also separate the two folder structures, so that they look something like this:

```
/var
    /www
        /<yourdomain>.com
            /www
                /htdocs
                    index.html and everything
                        else for your default
                        website goes here
            /<subdomain>
                /htdocs
                    index.html and everything
                        else for your Ushithingy
                        installation goes here
```

And adjust the docroots in your virtualhosts accordingly. The reason you should do this is that as long as one website is within the docroot of the other website, it's still possible to get to the second website via the first virtualhost definition - only then the pages would look all messed up because of the different docroot and the absolute hrefs in the pages. Another advantage of a well-ordered directory structure is that you can use mod_vhost_alias to define websites for many subdomains with one single simple virtualhost definition. But again, that's for later.

If you're done, restart your apache server, and it should be all good.